# Does the Honeywell D6X00 WinCE5.0 SDK work with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005, barcode-scanner, windows-mobile-5.0

I'm planning to develop an application targetting the Honeywell Dolphin 6100 running Win CE 5.0.  The documentation for the platform SDK and device SDK say that VS2005 is required to use them.

I don't have a copy of VS2005 and since it's not sold or supported by MS any more, I'd much rather buy VS2010.  Does anyone know if the Honeywell D6X00 SDKs are compatible with VS2010?

Thanks for your help!

Matt

Answer (score 1):

You can get access to VS2005 or VS2008 by purchasing VS2010 Pro with a MSDN subscription.  You can then download old versions of VS and other stuff from the MSDN site.  This is the path I have taken as there is lots of info on the web about how VS2010 does not support Win CE 5.0.  If you plan to only write straight C++, you can use embedded visual c++ 4.0 which you can download for free from MS.  If you have a lot of UI code, you may want to get VS2005.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2010 removed support for developing Windows Mobile devices (instead replacing that with support for Windows Phone) - you would need to get hold of Visual Studio 2008 (or 2005, as you mention), which should still be available.